# Differences in mailing from different servers

Tags: email, unix, tomcat, smtp, imap

I have a java application installed on unix server using a tomcat instance.
it has a feature which allows to send email to external user and get reply from their Outlook.

The sending and receiving process works well but when trying to reply on their reply from the application i'm getting an error:

```
There was an error sending a message. 
If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.
Error: No recipient addresses
```

When sending the first e-mail from the application, the "To" address is:

```
name.surname@domain.com
```

But when receiving the reply from the recipient it will turn to:

```
Surname, Name < name.surname@domain.com >;
```

From trying it from different server it will work and the only different is that the "To:" address looks like this:

```
"Surname, Name" < name.surname@domain.com >
```

Application on both servers using same outgoing/incoming mail servers.

What else can effect it and cause the above error?

Thanks.

Comment: The SMTP envelope must not have "quoted names", only an email address.  The mail headers may have these decorations.  Are you passing these headers verbatim to your SMTP code?  What IS your code?  How are you sending mail?

Comment: The application wasn't developed by us i only know it uses IMAP protocol, different hosts for outgoing and incoming emails, it's installed on Unix server, and on one server it works and the other it doesn't. Unfortunately this is all the information i have, and I just want to find out why there's different behavior in each server.